# BroadcastReceiver and wifiState

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm writing an application that needs to receive wifi state modification. To do it I've wrote a class, TestReceiver, that extends BroadcastReceiver and, now, write on Log.i.
The receiver has been registrated via AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.lazooo.wifi_finder_service">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <receiver android:name=".TestReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

and my TestReceiver is:

```
package com.lazooo.wifi_finder_service;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("BroadcastApplication", "ricevuto capo");
    Toast.makeText(context, "ciao", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

The matter is that it doesn't work, when I turn on/off wifi it doesn't do nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: How looks your TestReceiver? Do you have right package?

Comment: It looks good try to change manifest to `android:name="com.lazooo.wifi_finder_service.TestReceiver`

Comment: @Sajmon still nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Debug and see if anything is being sent. If the send is fine and you are still not receiving the message, my experience has been that with wifi, firewall issues may kick in and the message is not received. Any kind of notification seems to work better with data connectivity.

Comment: What do you mean? What should I check?